# I can't solve this error in Python

Tags: python

I can't solve [this problem](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-2W5v7/1/5?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#) in Python.

---

I wrote this code:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower();
first = word[0];
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    if first == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
        new_word =  word + pyg;
    else:
        new_word = word[1:] + first_2 + pyg;
        print new_word;
else: 
    print "Null";
```

But I get the following error after entering *Basic* word:

> Oops, try again! Your word started with a consonant, but "basicay" was printed instead of "asicbay".

Comment: First of all there is an error at the `if` statment, you have to evaluate `first` variable with all the vowels. `if first=='a' or first=='b' ...` You can use `str.startswith()` for this propouse

Comment: Python doesn't need `;` to end lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
if first == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
```

That essentially translates to this:

```
if (first == 'a') or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
```

and 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u' translate to "True" in Python, so that statement is *always* true.

You actually need to do the equality check for each letter:

```
if first == 'a' or first == 'e' or first == 'i' or first == 'o' or first == 'u':
```

But luckily, there's an easier way to do that in Python:

```
if first in "aeiou":
```

Comment: There is one difference, though, between the last two statements (not relevant for this use case, though): if `first` is `"ae"`, then `first in "aeiou"` will be `True`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: `first` should be a single character, based on this line: `first = word[0]`.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out that the two aren't equivalent. That's why I wrote "not relevant for this case".

Answer (score 3):

```
if first == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
```

evaluates to

```
if (first == 'a') or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
```

which is always true, because even if `first != 'a'`, the following part `'e'` is true.

Replace it with

```
if first in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
```

or, if `first` is always a single character:

```
if first in 'aeiou':
```

Also, Python doesn't need `;` at the end of lines.

Comment: The semicolon doesn't hurt, though.  If that's what it takes to convert 'em from Java/C#/C++/C...

Comment: @Makoto, Python doesn't need those people that have to be convinced to convert

Answer (score 1):

`if first == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'` stands out at me.

The reason for this:  Python will evaluate its boolean statements left to right, and interprets your statement as `if (first == 'a') or ('e') or ('i') or ('o') or ('u')`.  Any non-empty string is a "truthy" value, basically giving you back 'e'.

That's not the behavior you want.  You should change it to use `if first in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')`.